# Draw arrow from one cell edge to another cell edge

Tags: excel

In Excel, I want to draw an arrow from cell B2, right side, to cell C10, left side. This arrow should be coupled to the cells, so if I resize the cells, or cut-paste them to a new place, the arrow should move as well. Is there any way to accomplish this?

p.s. I would settle for a line instead of an arrow if this is easier.

Comment: I expect to draw an arrow, and edit the properties somewhere to connect the endpoints to certain cell positions. I don't know if this would be code, or properly filled in properties.

Comment: Has there been any progress to this question?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

### To add manually (in Excel):

- **Older Excel versions:** Go to the **Insert** menu -> **Shapes** -> **Arrow**
- **Excel 2016+:** Go to the **Insert** menu -> **Illustrations** -> **Shapes** -> select an arrow type.

Position the arrow on the sheet and use the grips to adjust the position.

---

### or with VBA:

```vb
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector( msoConnectorStraight, _
    Range("B2").Left, Range("B2").Top, Range("C10").Left, Range("C10").Top ).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
```

Adjust to the cells you want...

- Documentation from Microsoft: [Shapes.AddConnector method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addconnector)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't understand. What do you mean with "after with grip you can move"? I am also not familiar with code in Excel. Where do I type this? I tried at a random cell =code(your_first_line), but this resulted in an error.

Comment: Indeed I have drawn an arrow from one cell to another cell that I want. The disadvantage is that the arrow remains in its place if I copy-cut the cell to another location, so I was hoping I could somehow attach the arrow head to the cell. If I need macros to do that, then it's too cumbersome at this time.